# Can a Verilog In line Initialization cause an event?

Tags: verilog

Since in-line variable initialization will be executed during simulation time 0.Is there a chance that it might trigger an event at time 0 ? Please elaborate

Comment: Can you give an example?  I'm not 100% sure what you're asking.  What do you mean by cause an event?  Are you asking about simulation or synthesis?

Comment: I was asking about simulation. We all know that the code is executed once at time 0. So , I wanted to know if the value of a variable changes, will that trigger an event ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variable 'initialization' will always trigger an event. From the last Verilog standard([IEEE 1364-2005](http://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1364-2005.html)):

> If a variable declaration assignment is used (see 6.2.1), the variable
>   shall take this value as if the assignment occurred in a blocking
>   assignment in an initial construct.

Also be aware

> If the same variable is assigned different values both in an initial
>   block and in a variable declaration assignment, the order of the
>   evaluation is undefined.

Comment: Is this a copy from text book (see 6.2.1) ?

Comment: It's the Language Reference Manual - do a search for P1364-2005 and you should find a free draft version online. I don't think there any usable Verilog text books.

Answer (score 0):

A good reference for order of events is this paper:

http://www.sunburst-design.com/papers/CummingsSNUG2000SJ_NBA_rev1_2.pdf

page 6 has a diagram of the order of events as far as evaluation of variables and triggering goes.